# need to sum this table with substrings to find the correct value

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm stuck to sum the items in this table per id/rev.
I need the following result:

```
ID1   SYS1    +/-x items (delevered items - returned items)
ID1   SYS2    +/-x items
ID1   SYS3    +/-x items
ID2   SYS1    +/-x items
ID2   SYS2    +/-x items
ID2   SYS3    +/-x items
```

however i need to subtract only the value to calculate the sum.
I built a list with CASE WHEN (content='returned x items') THEN ELSE with all the possibilities from 0 to 99 but i don't think thats the way to go here.
delevered is plus, returned is minus

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `rev` varchar(200)NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL

) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('ID1', 'SYS1', 'returned 1 item'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'delivered 2 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS2', 'returned 41 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS3', 'returned 12 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'returned 12 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS1', 'delivered 11 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'returned 13 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS2', 'returned 14 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS2', 'delivered 11 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS2', 'returned 12 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS3', 'delivered 17 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS2', 'returned 11 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS1', 'delivered 14 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'returned 11 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'returned 14 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS2', 'delivered 11 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS1', 'returned 12 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'delivered 15 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS2', 'returned 11 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS1', 'delivered 14 items'),
  ('ID2', 'SYS1', 'returned 15 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS2', 'delivered 14 items'),
  ('ID1', 'SYS3', 'returned 18 items');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As variant you can use `REPLACE` function and then `CAST` string to `int`

```
SELECT
  *,
  IF(content LIKE 'returned%',-1,1)*CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(content,'delivered ',''),'returned ',''),' items',''),' item','') AS SIGNED) QtyVer1,
  IF(content LIKE 'returned%',-1,1)*SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(content,' ',-2),' ',1) QtyVer2
FROM docs
```

You also can try to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` - look at `QtyVer2`.

And a query with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
  id,
  rev,
  SUM(IF(content LIKE 'returned%',-1,1)*SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(content,' ',-2),' ',1)) Total
FROM docs
GROUP BY id,rev
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0611f/17

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE docs (
  tDate DATETIME NULL,
  id varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  rev varchar(200)NOT NULL,
  content varchar(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO docs (tDate, id, rev, content) VALUES
  ('2018-01-01 12:00','ID1', 'SYS1', 'returned 3 item'),
  ('2018-01-02 12:00','ID1', 'SYS2', 'delivered items: 4'),
  ('2018-01-03 12:00','ID2', 'SYS3', 'returned 2 item'),
  ('2018-01-03 14:10','ID1', 'RESET', ''),
  ('2018-01-04 12:00','ID2', 'SYS1', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-05 12:00','ID3', 'SYS2', 'returned 1 item'),
  ('2018-01-06 12:00','ID3', 'SYS3', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-07 12:00','ID2', 'SYS1', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-08 12:00','ID3', 'SYS2', 'returned 1 item'),
  ('2018-01-09 12:00','ID1', 'SYS2', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-10 12:00','ID3', 'SYS3', 'returned 3 item'),
  ('2018-01-10 12:10','ID1', 'RESET', ''),
  ('2018-01-10 13:00','ID2', 'SYS3', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-10 13:10','ID3', 'SYS1', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-10 13:20','ID2', 'SYS2', 'delivered items: 3'),
  ('2018-01-10 14:00','ID3', 'SYS1', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-10 14:10','ID3', 'RESET', ''),
  ('2018-01-11 12:00','ID1', 'SYS2', 'returned 2 item'),
  ('2018-01-11 13:00','ID1', 'SYS1', 'delivered items: 1'),
  ('2018-01-11 14:00','ID2', 'SYS2', 'delivered items: 3'),
  ('2018-01-11 15:00','ID2', 'SYS3', 'delivered items: 2'),
  ('2018-01-11 16:00','ID3', 'SYS2', 'returned 1 item'),
  ('2018-01-11 17:00','ID3', 'SYS1', 'delivered items: 2'),
  ('2018-01-11 17:10','ID2', 'RESET', ''),
  ('2018-01-11 18:00','ID2', 'SYS3', 'delivered items: 2'),
  ('2018-01-11 19:00','ID3', 'SYS2', 'returned 1 item');
```

hi, there is some new information for this summation:

records have a timestamp and I need the sum AFTER the last RESET for the different id's in the table.
For example, ID1 has a LAST reset on 2018-01-10 12:10, i only need the 3 SYSx sums after this date.
is it possible to have the 9 sums in one query?